# How to create cascading menus in rails?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use rails + bootstrap to build a web application.  I want create two select boxes like this:

The first select box:

[image]

If I select language, the second select box will show as below:

[image]

If I select platform, the second select box will show like this:

[image]

The code as below:

```
<%= form_tag(nil, :method=>'get', class: "form-inline") do %>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <%= select_tag(:lang, 
                options_for_select([['language', 1],['platform', 2]]),
                {class: "span2"}) %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

I created the first select box, but I don't know how to create second. I am not familiar with CSS, hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say you "don't know how to create the second", do you mean you need to know how to make the choices in the second box different based on the first box selection?

Comment: You'll need to use javascript. Are you using jQuery or another library?

Comment: I installed the gem package 'jquery-rails',but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a good example from railscast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus